# Using ERB for Nesta layout and page templates

Tags: ruby, erb, nestacms

I'm trying to get [Nesta](http://nestacms.com/) to use .erb templates for layout and page templates, but confused as to how to go about it.

With partials, it's easy:

```
= haml :header, :layout => false
```

becomes:

```
= erb :header, :layout => false
```

However, I can't figure out how to have all my pages point to a `layout.erb` file instead of a `layout.haml` file.

According to [this](http://nestacms.com/docs/design/templating-engines), `.erb` templates seem fully supported, though they only describe how to apply them for individual routes. While confusingly in [this post](http://nestacms.com/blog/version-0-9-13) it says that *"features include support for Erb templates (in the views folder only, not for pages)"*?

Does anyone have a better understanding of this?